# Arduino datalogging weird shapes

Tags: logging, arduino, sd-card

I want to read two inputs and right them on SD card and then if condition is met tweet something.
The problem is after some iterations I get weird shapes instead of numbers and the program freezes. 
Worth saying that arduino is away from the source and so is connected via a shielded wire to reject noise.

Any one faced same problem?

I tried the code connecting one leg of a resistor to `5V` and the other to `A0` and 
the same for `A1` and I didn't face any problem writing them on SD ; and if not 
connected it generates random numbers which also works fine!.

worth saying last line `while (1>0)` is due to the need for continuous tweeting.

### Source Code

```
#include <SPI.h> 
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Twitter.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;
char ssid[] = "...";  
char pass[] = "...";  

Twitter twitter("..."); 

int PV;
int LDR;

char tweetText[140];

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(0,INPUT);
    while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
        Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        if (!SD.begin(4)) 
        {
            Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
            return;
        }
        Serial.println("card initialized.");
        delay(10000);
    }
}

void tweet(char msg[]) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to Twitter");
    if(twitter.post(msg))
    {
        int status = twitter.wait(&Serial);
        if (status==200){
            Serial.println("Successful");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Tweet failed.");
            Serial.println(status);
        }
    } else {
        Serial.println("Connection to Twitter failed");
        Serial.println("20 Seconds timeout started");
        delay(20000);
    }
} 

void loop() {
    String dataString="";
    // read PV voltage from A0 and A1 then append to the string
    do {
        for (int analogPin=0; analogPin<2; analogPin++) {
            PV = analogRead(0);
            LDR= analogRead(1);
            int sensor=analogRead(analogPin);
            dataString += String(sensor);
            if (analogPin<1){
                dataString += ",";
            }
        }

        File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
        if (dataFile) {
            dataFile.println(dataString);
            dataFile.close();
            Serial.println(dataString);
        } else {
            Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
        }

        if(PV>=1023) {
            Serial.println(PV);
            sprintf(tweetText,"A0>5volts and reads: %d. @MeghdadiAli." , PV, LDR);
            delay(50000);
            tweet(tweetText);
            Serial.println("A0>5volts");
        } else {
            Serial.println(PV);
            sprintf(tweetText,"A0<5volts and reads: %d. @MeghdadiAli.", PV, LDR);
            delay(50000);
            tweet(tweetText);
            Serial.println("A0 is not 5volts");
        }
    } while(1>0);
}
```

### Expected output

it should write amount of A0 and A1 at each iteration and then write it beside the previous data written on SD

### Obtained output

Here is what I got last time:

```
1023,1011, 1023,1011,1023,1008, 1023,1011023,1008,1023r 1023,
1011023,1008023r 1023r ´z #þ½.D" " _DATALOG TXT 1023,997 - 23,
1011023 ë 10r 1023,997 - 23,1011023 ë 10r
```

(line breaks added for commodity)

Comment: Your "weird shapes" are probably random binary numbers which do not correspond to normal alphanumeric ASCII characters being interpreted as extended "drawing" characters.  This is likely either a result of misunderstanding the format of data, random noise, or program errors causing you to print random memory outside of your buffers.

Comment: well, first, ali-meghdadi, you should read http://sscce.org to help us help you more efficiently. Basically, you should update your question with the code, the expected output and the real output, and try to shrink your code into a minimal example. Until you do that, I agree with @chris-stratton that you're certainly overflowing and writing random memory.

Comment: @zmo - please take a minute to think about the nature of the problem, it's going to be pretty hard to provide an "sscce" for a project with hardware components.

Comment: @chrisstratton I do not agree, there's a high probability his problem is software. So to be able to help him solve his problem, he needs to give us code (shrunk as possible), expected output, obtained output.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited my post and added part of my code. After three iterations it starts giving the shapes and then the program freezes. @Chris Stratton

Comment: Also about expected output @zmo I should say the maximum output is around 20volts and using a voltage divider it should be 5volts or less which is equal to 1023 but I get some random shapes and then the software stops working. Based on the code, it should write amount of A0 and A1 at each iteration and then write it beside the previous data written on SD. Here is what I got last time:1023,1011, 1023,1011,1023,1008, 1023,1011023,1008,1023r 1023,1011023,1008023r 1023r ´z #þ½.D" " _DATALOG TXT 1023,997 - 23,1011023 ë 10r 1023,997 - 23,1011023 ë 10r

Comment: tweetText how is declared? Where is tweet function? Btw seems you are creating garbage somwhere or writing in wrong ram position. Full code is needed to find the leak

Comment: @lesto as I mentioned before the code works perfect while testing it with a resistor but anyways here is the whole code.

Comment: tweetText Is very big, try to lower it. Aldko PV and LDR inside loop has no meaning, as the comma if should probably be >0. Also because of do while loop dataString is NEVER cleared, causing an overflow

Comment: @lesto you think while loop is the problem? So why it worked when I was testing it? Also, in order to tweet continuously, do you have suggestions?

Comment: It is not the loop, but the fact that dataString is never cleared, it will grow larger until ram overflow occur. Maybe it was working because you was declaring the variable INSIDE the loop, starting with a clear variable every iteration instead of adding

Comment: but it's based on arduino Datalogger example and the while we are talking about is inevitable!...so @lesto you got any suggestion on how to change it?

Comment: @ChrisStratton see, I was right ;-) and ali, glad to see you've got your issue solved thanks to lesto.

Comment: @zmo - no, you were wrong.  While I'll agree the code is helpful, you asked for a self contained example, to quote from your reference, "Self Contained - Ensure everything is included, ready to go." That was not provided, and could not be provided for an embedded project.  If you didn't expect an example you could actually run yourself, you should have said so, instead of linking to sscce.

Comment: a sscce would have been possible! As the problem was about writing data on the SD, he could have given us only the `void loop()` part of his code, and not the other functions. It was obviously not a hardware problem, but some kind of BoF, and I was expecting something like the `String` declaration he made. It's not because it's embedded that everything has to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are createing a `do{}while` loop inside the `loop()`, that has no meaning as they do the same things, infact if you look at the .cpp created in the temp folder (activate "verbose compiling" from the menu), you will find something similar to;

```
int main(){
  setup();
  while(1){
    loop();
  }
}
```

BUT

`String dataString="";` is called only one time, then `dataString` is modified only ADDING char, so it will grow until it will overflow and do bad things to your ram.

Infact, if you look at the SD file, you should find

```
read1,
read1, read1, read2,
read1, read1, read2, read1, read1, read2, read3,
```

and so on

There are 2 solution:

1. remove the `do{}while` loop as it is rendoundant, that way `dataString` will be destroied at the end of the loop, and recreated (empty) at the beginning;
2. `dataString = "";` before the between the `do{` and `for`, that will not destroy and recreate the variable, but just clear its value.

Comment: Hi again folks, Does anyone ever faced a kind of error in reading the input by arduinoinput? I used a voltage divider to decrease the input voltage but the thing is no matter what the voltage is (11,12,..., 20) I get "1023" as input!!! Does anyone have any Idea?

Comment: wait, are you putting more than 5V in an arduino pin? just that should fry it, if it does not, thanks atmel's guru to make their chip like a tank.

the input voltage absolute max is == to VCC (normally 5V), if using the ADC (analogRead()) input should be < AnalogReference. It is 5V by default, but you can change it using a function and/or giving a reference voltage to AREF pin

Comment: yes it is and I decreased it using voltage divider using a 1k and a 4k resistor so the input to arduino is less than 5. I know Im getting analog input but I don't understand why it always shows 1023 whether the source is 20 or 11!

Comment: did you mesured the voltage with a multimeter? also without schema is hard to tell

Comment: @lesto yes I measured using a multimeter. The thing is I want to measure a photovoltaic panel (solar panel) voltage which varies from zero to twenty and record them in the SD card using arduino. I have my code above also. (I wanted to attach a scheme of system but it seems I cannot)

Comment: Hi @lesto, Have you ever faced Arduino stopped from tweeting?​ mine goes whole day but I guess it's ram will be full and stops tweeting. Based on my code there should not be a problem right?

Comment: Everything internet related is border line. On the official site, on the playgroud, you can find a library that tell you the free memory at runtime. Try to track it down, and trybto find where and why the program stop. Maybe is an error on the spi bus (sd and wifi enabled together) or a bug in the twitter lib